# document referrer location javascript remote php server

Tags: php, javascript, location, referrer

I have following code to get a referrer in Javascript  mode in a web page that don't support PHP and pass it to remote server: `http://site.com/ref.php` where with `$ref = $_GET['referrer'];` I get the referrer I want get also location i.e site where is installed script in my remote server with `$loc = $_GET['location'];`  so I must insert `document.location` in this script but I don't know how now.

```
<script>
var src = "http://site.com/ref.php"
src += "?referrer=" + escape( document.referrer );
src += "&anticache=" + new Date().getTime();
var body = document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[0];
var image = document.createElement( "img" );
image.src = src;
body.appendChild( image );
</script>
```

I have tried to add to script 
`src += "?location=" + escape( document.location );` but don't work 
any help?

Comment: love the antichache technique

Comment: There's no need to append the image element to the body - just setting the "src" attribute will cause an HTTP transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
src += "?location=" + escape( document.location );
```

If you're putting this after the `referrer` or `anticache` argument, you've already got the `?`; what you want is a `&` to separate two arguments.

Use `location.href` in preference to `document.location`, and `encodeURIComponent` in preference to `escape`.

Comment: <script>
var src = "http://site.com/ref.php"
src += "?location=" + encodeURIComponent( location.href );
src += "?referrer=" + escape( document.referrer );
src += "&anticache=" + new Date().getTime();
var body = document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[0];
var image = document.createElement( "img" );
image.src = src;
body.appendChild( image );
</script>
      i' have tried but don't work give me correct code if you can

Comment: You still have two `?`s, one before `location` and one before `referrer`. The second has to be a `&`.

Comment: Oh, and the `encodeURIComponent` goes for `referrer` too... there's almost never any reason to use `escape` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because the `document.location` is an object containing many information: [see?](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp). Try `document.location.href`

Code:

```
var src = "http://site.com/ref.php"
src += "?referrer=" + escape( document.referrer );
src += "&anticache=" + new Date().getTime();
src += "&location=" + encodeURIComponent( location.href );
```

Comment: the problem is that if i add to script row src += "?location=" + escape( document.location.href ); the script don't work any more and i don't get nothing no referrer no location